# WPF MVVM get row object after the DataGridHyperlinkColumn click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using WPF MVVM pattern and have a DataGrid like:

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=displayedResults}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Operation" Binding="{Binding Path=Mode}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=Result, Converter={StaticResource EnumToString}}" />
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Width="100" Header="Details" ContentBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource DetailsLink}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The DetailsLink static resource represents the text "Link". When the DataGrid fills, each row has the last column with the link, that will allow users to see details. To show details I need to get the whole object at the line the link "Link" was clicked.

Unfortunately, I haven't found the solution yet. May be there is an obvious decision? :)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share `DetailsLink` xaml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to pass parameters then you better use an `ICommand`, so create a `DataTemplate` rather than using the HyperLinkColoumn as the following:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Link">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock>
                      <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToLinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Link, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                       </Hyperlink>
                     </TextBlock>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now create a command called `NavigateToLinkCommand` and a string Property called `Link` in your ViewModel and the current row `DataContext` will be passed as the parameter of your `Command`, and note the `AncestorType` DataContext that your `ViewModel` is set to.